# collection level access control with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, express, mongoose

I am trying to implement collection level access control using mongoose in my web application. I have created users with different roles. User with superadmin role can do anything however user with guest can read all the collections values but can only write to certain collections.

But with mongoose, i am finding it extremely difficult to implement this feature. With mongodb native driver we can exports db object based on user role and query the database with db.collections object but with mongoose i am not sure.

Should i create multiple connections at the initial and then pass the connection object based on user role to the model file and create mongoose model every time user role changes or what do i do?

I have done a lot of coding with mongoose. so i cannot choose mongodb native driver. How do i do it? please suggest